# Creating a photo that transfers from one viewcontroller to another

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview

So basically I have `UIButtons` with different images as the buttons and a `UIImageView` in a different view controller. I want that when I click on one of the buttons, the image of the button will show up in the `UIImageview` in a different view controller.

Think of it as selecting a character in a game so when you select that character you play as that character.

Comment: Are you using Storyboards?

Comment: duplicate of thousands of other questions about passing data between view controllers.

Answer (score 1):

So give the second VC (view controller) an image property. When you click the button, invoke a segue, and then in prepareForSegue, set the image property in the second VC.

In the second VC's viewWillAppear, take the image property and install it in the image view.

Comment: thank you but could you elaborate on how to invoke a segue  and the prepareForSegue

Comment: Put some effort into it. Go do some searching on prepareFromSegue. Try it. If you have trouble, post the code that you're struggling with.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"toDifferentViewController"]) 
{
    UIImage *testImg;
    testImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Test.png"];
    differentViewController *destVC = segue.destinationViewController;
    destVC.passedImage = testImg;
}
```

In differentViewController.h set the property:

```
@property UIImage *passedImage;
```

in .m synthesize and use your UIImage as needed

```
@Synthesize passedImage;
```

Comment: do i need to have two different .h .m for each of the view controllers @BossBols

Comment: Every time you create a class file that inherits from UIViewController for example Xcode will automatically create the relevant .h and .m, which are needed yes!

Comment: No, you don't need to put all class interfaces and implementation in different files — but you want it!